# Asterisk v13 on Kali Linux: No RTP engine was found. Do you have one loaded?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, asterisk, voip, sip

I installed Asterisk and tried to make a call with zoiper
but I get an error [call failure 401 forbidden] 
and Asterisk return this message :

```
Connected to Asterisk UNKNOWN__and_probably_unsupported currently running on kali (pid = 14877)
[Jan 22 17:57:00] ERROR[14937][C-00000007]: rtp_engine.c:401 ast_rtp_instance_new: No RTP engine was found. Do you have one loaded?
[Jan 22 17:57:00] NOTICE[14937][C-00000007]: chan_sip.c:25550 handle_request_invite: Failed to authenticate device <sip:5002@192.168.88.135;transport=UDP>;tag=9a473a54
```

I opened the menuselect and selected `res_rtp_asterisk`.

When I try to reinstall (recompile!) Asterisk, I do `./configure`

This says it's ok! But when I put `make` or `make install`, I get this error:

```
CC="cc" CXX="g++" LD="" AR="" RANLIB="" CFLAGS="" LDFLAGS="" make -C menuselect CONFIGURE_SILENT="--silent" makeopts
make[1]: Entering directory `/etc/asterisk/asterisk/menuselect'
make[1]: `makeopts' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/etc/asterisk/asterisk/menuselect'
   [CC] res_rtp_asterisk.c -> res_rtp_asterisk.o
res_rtp_asterisk.c: In function ‘ice_create’:
res_rtp_asterisk.c:2421:4: error: too many arguments to function ‘pj_ice_sess_create’
In file included from /usr/include/pjnath.h:23:0,
                 from res_rtp_asterisk.c:53:
/usr/include/pjnath/ice_session.h:736:22: note: declared here
make[1]: *** [res_rtp_asterisk.o] Error 1
make: *** [res] Error
```

Comment: If you do not have the experience to compile it, install the packages and configure them. asterisk is not a trivial thing to setup.

Comment: so ????????????

Comment: Kali isn't the distribution I'd choose to run Asterisk from.

Comment: it's the same as debian distributions !!

Comment: No, it is not.  Also recommended for asterisk is rhel/centos.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
make menuconfig
```

before compile.

Find res_rtp_asterisk and check if it need some dependency you not have or just turned off. If it turned off, turn it on and recompile.